# Moving Dates, Text, and Currency to New Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a large set of transaction that are contained in Column A as shown.

[image]

I am trying to keeps dates in column A, description in column B, and cost in column C like the example below.

[image]

I am not sure how to do this while keeping the dates to the corresponding transactions. Some dates have 10 transactions occurred while others have none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged your post with microsoft-excel-2010, which makes this kind of thing quite difficult. In case that was accidental, or in case it helps others, you can do something like this in recent versions of Excel.

[image]

In cell B2:

```
=LET(days,TRANSPOSE(TEXT(DATE(2022,1,SEQUENCE(7,1,17)),"dddd")),isdate,XLOOKUP(IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1),""),days,days,"")<>"",IF(isdate,A2,B1))
```

This is then dragged down to the bottom of the data range (B18 in the image)

In cell C2 and copied down in column C:

```
=IF(AND(A2<>B2,NOT(ISNUMBER(A2))),A2,C1)&""
```

In cell D2 and copied down in column D:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),A2,"")
```

Then finally, in cell B22 in the image:

```
=FILTER($B$2:$D$18,$D$2:$D$18<>"")
```

You can add logic to convert the date as text to a date format if you wish.

EDIT:

For Excel 2010, I think you can use this for the column the puts the date on each row (in column F in the image below):

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(LEFT($A3,FIND(",",$A3)-1),{"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday";"Saturday";"Sunday"})>0)),$A3,F2)
```

The formulas for the other two columns are the same and of course, in Excel 2010 you will not have access to FILTER, so you'll have to use Autofilter or Advanced Filter to remove the unnecessary rows.

[image]

Comment: That solution worked for me. Thank you. I removed the Microsoft Excel 10 tag since I was mistaken in adding that.